# Using SAS to change date fields on a daily run script to automate it

Tags: sas

The following variable are in my current SAS script, that is run daily.

I have to change the following

%let begdt = '22Feb16 00:00:00.0'dt ;

%let enddt = '23Feb16 03:00:00.0'dt ;

%let sync_int = 600;

%let ginterval='01:00:00.0't ;

filename filein (

'C:\PROD\2016\GZ\02.23.16\data02_23_031500.tsv'

);

to the following (So for today - ie the 24th) it will look like this

`%let begdt = '23Feb16 00:00:00.0'dt ;

%let enddt = '24Feb16 03:00:00.0'dt ;

%let sync_int = 600;

%let ginterval='01:00:00.0't ;

filename filein (

'C:\PROD\2016\GZ\02.24.16\data02_24_031500.tsv'

);

In the first line

I change 22Feb16 to 23Feb16... It needs to be the previous day's date

In the 2nd line

I change 23Fed16 to 24Feb14 - it needs to be today's date

and in the file name

I have to change the Folder name freom 02.23.16 to 02.24.16 and the file name from data02_23_ to data02_24_

Basically it's a script that I run daily (manually). I am trying to use SAS to detect what day it is when it runs, and have it change those date fields - so I can set it to run on my SAS server each day without having to change any code... I was trying to use what was avabilable to me - but as you can see I am struggling with it...  Ive been handed the script and am stuck..

Any help is greatly appreciated....  I tried the best I could to see if I could figure it out - but haven't figured it out yet

Comment: Suggest you include the code you have tried. If you include that, people will be able to explain why it didn't work, which is often more helpful in the long run than someone giving you working code alone.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use SAS to detect what day it is when it runs

Well good question, you can use Today(), Date(), or Datetime()

This should help too

http://www.lexjansen.com/pnwsug/2004/DateAndTime.pdf